# Why don't remember brightness (U14.04, Samsung Ativ book 9 lite)

Tags: display, screen, brightness

Why Ubuntu doesn't remember the screen brightness ? Whenever I turn it on, it always returns to the max, even if I set on settings.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's likely a flaw, (bug) or shortcoming in Upstart. 15.10/16.04 with systemd will preserve brightness setting across reboots/fresh boot ups